# How to include csrf_token() in an external js file in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Initially, I wrote all the JavaScript code right in my HTML page using the `<script>` tag.

A post call in jQuery in the JavaScript was something like this.

```
$.post('store',{'_token':'{{csrf_token()}}'}, function(data){ /*a bunch of code*/ });
```

The code worked fine. But, later I put all my script into an external js file. And the code is not working anymore.

I have the problem with the `{{csrf_token()}}`, the error being

> TokenMismatchException in compiled.php

What should I do if I want to external js files with Laravel?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

1. add `<meta>` tag with the token to the blade layout:

```html
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

2. setup ajax requests:

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
});
```

Now you can use `$.post()` without providing `_token` each time.

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed The documentation for this can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var csrf = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
```